# Plants grown in planet’s soil allow colonist to adapt to atmosphere

Tags: biology, planets, atmosphere

Is there a toxin which could plausibly exist in the atmosphere of a planet, which could make people sick but not too sick?

Is it possible that plants grown in the soil from this planet might be able to provide something to the colonists which allows them to resist, filter or live with this possible toxin.  How would this work?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding.SE.  When you get a moment, take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.  With very rare exception, you should ask only one question (this Q asks so many it's too broad and will be closed).  Also, it is very difficult for us to simply invent biology because with so many variables it's opinion-based with no clear answer.  Finally: we're here to help you build a world, not tell a story.  "How are the plants providing the answer" is telling the story.  Please narrow your question considerably.  Thanks.

Comment: Relevant Meta-Question on High-concept "no work" questions [I have a high concept please do the work for me](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions). Also the array of possible inorganic toxins in this scenario is broad enough, the array of organic compounds that _could be_ involved or dreamed up is all but infinite.

Comment: The list of questions you ask would arguably be the basis for the story outline - I can see a hero running around trying to find answers.  You're almost asking us to write the story for you.

Comment: I was scrambling to answer this before the close voters got it.   I was too slow.  I have edited it to hopefully answer objections.  I think it is a cool idea and very doable.

Comment: ST:TOS did it 60 years ago. http://www.startrek.com/database_article/this-side-of-paradise  (And Spock fell in love with a serious hottie.)

Comment: @RonJohn a direct quote from your source: "A beautiful botanist on Omicon Ceti III, Kalomi was infected with "happiness" spores. She exposed Spock to the spores in 2267, hoping he would love her. Eventually, she lost the spores and Spock's love." brb dying xD

Answer (score 4):

I propose that your atmospheric toxin is **bromine**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromine

> The bromide anion is not very toxic... However, high levels of bromide
>   chronically impair the membrane of neurons, which progressively
>   impairs neuronal transmission, leading to toxicity, known as
>   bromism... . Historically, the therapeutic dose of bromide is about 3
>   to 5 grams of bromide, thus explaining why chronic toxicity (bromism)
>   was once so common. While significant and sometimes serious
>   disturbances occur to neurologic, psychiatric, dermatological, and
>   gastrointestinal functions, death from bromism is rare. Bromism is
>   caused by a neurotoxic effect on the brain which results in
>   somnolence, psychosis, seizures and delirium.
>
> Elemental bromine is toxic and causes chemical burns on human flesh.
>   Inhaling bromine gas results in similar irritation of the respiratory
>   tract, causing coughing, choking, and shortness of breath, and death
>   if inhaled in large enough amounts. Chronic exposure may lead to
>   frequent bronchial infections and a general deterioration of health.
>   As a strong oxidising agent, bromine is incompatible with most organic
>   and inorganic compounds.

Your colonists suffer from bromine in the environment.  I think the neurotoxic stuff would make for more interesting writing than the elemental bromine.

They grow plants in the soil.  [Certain plants can tolerate high levels of bromine](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/srx.ecology/2010/650678/ref/).  I am not sure what the mechanism is (I could not turn it up!) but perhaps these plants overproduce peptides or other molecules with a high affinity for bromine.  I could imagine that this might be something which is upregulated in a a high bromine environment, or selected for in plants which live in such environments.  In any case: this molecule scavenges it up.  When the colonists eat the plants they gain the bromine scavenging power for their own bodies.

As regards prospects for cleaning up the planet, bromine cannot be destroyed but it can be bound up in harmless forms.  Maybe if these plants spread over the planet they will bind up all the bromine and hold it in their decomposing bodies.  You will ultimately wind up with bromine rich peat and coal.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is literally under our nose: carbon dioxide.

- It is toxic to aerobic organism.
- Plants remove them from the atmosphere and convert it into the more appreciated Oxygen.

As colonists don't want to suffocate as they step out of the ship, they will have to plant a lot of plants and have them produce enough Oxygen to sustain life.

This happened on our planet during the so called [great oxygenation event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be possible.  As an example system, research has been done on the protection afforded by dietary antioxidants again ozone in the atmosphere.

Here is the [abstract](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11549539).

In summary, dietary antioxidants did protect to some degree against atmospheric ozone exposure.